# How can I get a motherboard driver on my new computer without an optical drive?

Tags: drivers, motherboard

I just built a new computer and I cannot get it to boot. it gets to the point where I can run a windows repair but then it tells me it is likely a driver issue. However I have no optical drive on this computer.
Is there a way to get the drivers on my computer so I can boot? Or is there some other problem.

Comment: You built a new computer, yet you got windows installed? Did you just move a harddrive from an older computer? Because if that's the case and you're running XP, it's extremely unlikely that the OS will survive a motherboard model change. Besides, when getting entirely new hardware, you should start with a fresh installation anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a USB drive with the loaded drivers.  Windows Vista and 7 can load drivers from a flash drive during the setup and/or repair.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reach the setup/install part of Windows 7? or are you stuck at the hard disk selection screen.

Make sure your BIOS setting for the hard disk are ok (AHCI)

Also, you installed Windows, and after a restart it will not boot, it is a problem of partitioning (Windows 7 requires a small, 100Mb, partition to store it's boot record)

Answer (score 0):

You can try switching the hard disk to IDE or legacy mode in the BIOS. The setting goes by many different names, so I cannot tell you which setting it is in your BIOS.

After you downgrade the disk, the installation should see the drive, and install just fine.

Once you installed the chipset / disk drivers in your new installation, you can crank up the disk settings to have proper performance.